# C Program can find (via fopen) in gdb but not release (a.out)

Tags: c, file-io

Here's a C simple program, that reads a user input for a file location and prints the first line if such exists:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    // init vars for user input, error checking
    char file[PATH_MAX];
    scanf("%s", file);
    errno = 0;
    FILE *contents = fopen(file, "r");

    // debug, check if file exists and raises error if not
    if (contents == NULL || errno != 0) {
        printf("Error raised: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    char example[1024] = "";
    fgets(example, 1024, contents);
    printf("%s", example);
    
    // necessary closing of the stream
    fclose(contents);

    return 0;
}
```

Running the code on debug (gdb) works fine, I just input the file location that is on the same directory and it works fine. But running something like `cat file.txt | ./a.out` won't work; apparently, `strerror()` returns `No such file or directory`. I don't know enough of C to know how undefined behavior may come into play, but all I know is that it must have something to do with `fopen`.

Either way, I'm just hoping to either have an alternative working solution or to know why the debugger can do something an executable can't.

Comment: Do you intend to do `echo file.txt` instead of `cat file.txt`?

Comment: You should just check `if( contents == NULL ) { perror(file); ...}`.  `fopen` is not required to leave `errno` unmodified when it returns succesfully.

Comment: You must always check the value returned by `scanf`.  If `file.txt` does not exist or is empty, then `cat` will produce no output and `scanf` will not modify `file`.  In that case, attempting `fopen(file, "r");` is undefined behavior since `file` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to word this precisely, but `cat` directly feeds the contents of the txt into the program... evidently it began trying to find a non-existent file. Running the executable works since the program works by getting the file directory, then searching for it, and the rest is history.

Example solution: run a scanf/fgets (whatever preference) until EOF/NULL into some variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect all you really need to do is `echo file.txt | ./a.out`, but there are other issues with your code.  It is much cleaner to read the filename from a parameter rather than from stdin.  If you do read from stdin using `scanf`, you should limit the amount of data read to prevent a buffer overflow, and you must always check the value returned by scanf to know whether or not it actually read any data.  You cannot assume that a non-zero value for errno represents an error.  Functions that complete successfully are not obligated to avoid changing errno and may leave it with a non-zero value.  Perhaps try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char file[PATH_MAX];
        char fmt[64];
        snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%%ds", PATH_MAX - 1);
        if( scanf(fmt, file) == 1 ){
                FILE *contents = fopen(file, "r");
                if( contents == NULL ) {
                        perror(file);
                        return 1;
                }

                char example[1024];
                fgets(example, 1024, contents);
                printf("%s", example);
                fclose(contents);
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

But it's really a *lot* cleaner to avoid scanf and just do `const char *path = argv[1]` or similar.

Note that `scanf` with `%s` is unsuited to this task, since it will be impossible to read filenames which contain whitespace. `fgets` is no better, since names can also include newlines.

Comment: Hello, I read through your comments and yes I intend and would like it to work with `cat`.  It works with `echo`, but not `cat`, which is boggling me. I tried your edit and it doesn't seem to work still; `cat file.txt | ./a.out` still returns `No such file or directory`...

Using command line arguments doesn't seem to work either, unless I'm doing something wrong, it returns error `Bad address`

Comment: What is the content of the file `file.txt`?   If that file exists and contains the name of a file that you want to open, then `cat` will work just fine.  If it does not exist, then `cat` cannot work.

Comment: It seems likely that `No such fikle or directory` is the error message being written by `cat`.  This is a strong argument for including the name of the program in the error message itself as is done by the underused `err` family.  `Bad address` would indicate that you are indeed using `argv` incorrectly.  You can do things like `const char * path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "default-path";`

Comment: Nevermind, it seems I've figured out why; and it invariably goes with how `cat` and running the exe works. It seems that I'm able to get it to work with a while loop + scanf to EOF. I guess that `cat` is feeding each character or word at a time... Anyhow thanks for your time.